# .htaccess - Tests if string is an existing file - string contain double pairs of parenthesis "()()"

Tags: .htaccess

This is the structure of site:

```
/
/.htaccess
/resources/
/resources/.htaccess
/resources/api.php
```

In root folder '/' I have this minimal `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . - [R=404,L]
```

In my '/resources' folder I have this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)/?$ api.php?file=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If I try to access resources (files does not exist) like:

```
example.com/resources/files/blabla.jpg
example.com/resources/files/anotherfile?v1
```

everything is OK and the /resources/api.php is hit with:

```
example.com/resources/files/file.jpg?file=blabla.jpg
example.com/resources/files/file.jpg?file=anotherfile&v1
```

But if I try a resource like

```
example.com/resources/files/a(1)(1)
example.com/resources/files/(dd)(sd)sd
```

the request remain at `/.htaccess` level and never hits `/resources/api.php`, redirecting to 404 error page.

Can someone explain why any request contain double pairs of parenthesis "()()" it behaves like this and how could I solve the situation?

Comment: Can't come up with an explanation off the top of my head, perhaps somehow URL encoding of the braces gets involved ... Suggest you go enable some rewrite logging, then you can go and check in detail what exactly happens.